If $9^{x+1} + (a^2 - 4a - 2)3^x + 1> 0$ for all $x ∈ R$, then which of the following is true?
If $9^{x+1} + (a^2 - 4a - 2)3^x + 1> 0$ for all $x ∈ R$, then which of the following is true?
The options given are as follows :
a) $a ∈ R$
b) $a ∈ R^+$
c) $a ∈  [1,∞)$
d) $a ∈ R -$ {2}
The answer is option 'd' with the justification given in my book as follows:
Let $3^x = y$. Then, we have
$9y^2 + (a^2 - 4a - 2)y + 1> 0$
⟹ $y(9y + (a^2 - 4a - 2) + \frac{1}{y}> 0$ for all $y>0$
⟹ $(3√y - \frac{1}{√y})^2 + (a-2)^2 > 0$ for all $y>0$
⟹ $a ≠ 2 ⟹ a ∈ R -$ {2}
My question is, how does the last step imply that $a ≠ 2$? Even if $a = 2$, the other term, i.e, $(3√y - \frac{1}{√y})^2$ is always positive. So, on what basis is this answer found?
Any help would be appreciated.

$(3\sqrt{y} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}})^2$ is $0$ with $y = \frac{1}{3}$

If $(3√y - \frac{1}{√y})^2 + (a-2)^2 > 0$ holds for all $y>0$ then it holds for $y=\frac13$, i.e. $(a-2)^2 > 0$.

I got your point. By the way, how did you go about finding the value of $y = \frac{1}{3}$? Was it just by intuition?

I solved $(3√y - \frac{1}{√y})^2=0$.
